# Let mypy warn about equality checks of variables with different type

Tags: python-3.x, types, static-typing, mypy

`mypy --strict` allows the following minimal example without any error:

```
a: int = 1
b: str = '1'

if a == b:
    pass
else:
    pass
```

Is there a possibility to make it issue an error (or at least a warning) about the `if a == b:` line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** My original answer below described how to implement this by writing a custom mypy plugin.

However, [as of mypy 0.700](https://mypy-lang.blogspot.com/2019/04/mypy-0700-released-up-to-4x-faster.html), this is now possible to do directly via the `--strict-equality` flag. Note that as of time of writing, this flag is not enabled by default via the `--strict` flag.

For example, running mypy on the original program above will produce the following error:

```
test.py:4: error: Non-overlapping equality check (left operand type: "int", right operand type: "str")
```

You can find more details about this flag near the bottom of the [Miscellaneous strictness options](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#miscellaneous-strictness-flags) section of the mypy command line flags doc.

---

This is possible using the (currently experimental and undocumented) plugins API.

In short, add the following file somewhere within your project:

```
from typing import Callable, Optional, Type
from mypy.plugin import MethodContext, Plugin
from mypy.meet import is_overlapping_types

class StrictEqualityPlugin(Plugin):
    def get_method_hook(self, fullname: str) -> Optional[Callable[[MethodContext], Type]]:
        if fullname.endswith('__eq__') or fullname.endswith('__ne__'):
            return strict_check_callback

def strict_check_callback(ctx: MethodContext) -> Type:
    if len(ctx.arg_types) == 1 and len(ctx.arg_types[0]) == 1:
        # Note: Expressions of the form 'base_type == arg_type' get
        # translated into `base_type.__eq__(arg_type)`.
        base_type = ctx.type
        arg_type = ctx.arg_types[0][0]

        # Two types are overlapping if one of the types could potentially be the
        # same as or a subtype of the other.
        #
        # If you want something even stricter, add `from mypy.sametypes import is_same_type`
        # up at the top and call `is_same_type` instead of `is_overlapping_types`.
        if not is_overlapping_types(base_type, arg_type):
            ctx.api.msg.warn(
                "The left and right operands have disjoint types ({} and {})".format(
                    ctx.api.msg.format(base_type),
                    ctx.api.msg.format(arg_type),
                ), 
                ctx.context)
    return ctx.default_return_type

def plugin(mypy_version: str) -> Plugin:
    return StrictEqualityPlugin
```

Let's assume that the name of this file is `strict_equality_plugins.py`.

Then, within the top-level of your project, create a [`mypy.ini`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_file.html) file. The file should, at the bare minimum, contain the following:

```
[mypy]
plugins = ./path/to/strict_equality_plugins.py
```

Then, running mypy within your root project will produce errors like the following:

> foo.py:1: warning: The left and right operands have disjoint types ("int" and "str")

**Disclaimer:** The plugin API of the mypy project is highly experimental -- I make no promises that this plugin will continue to work unmodified in future versions of mypy.